# Equivalence of different regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

If I have a two regular expressions, and want to check whether these two expressions are equivalent, how can it be done?

By "equivalence", I mean *do the two regular expressions match exactly the same set of strings?*

For example, these two regular expressions are equivalent:

```
b{1}b{0,} == bb*
```

These two are not.

```
b != bb*
```

An answer with code in Python would be ideal.

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear , please ? I don't understand.

Comment: @Onilol i believe, based on the example OP gave, that OP wants to check if two arbitrary regular expressions produce the same result set. In their case, `b{1}b{0,} == bb*` this would be true and `b{2}b{2,} == bb+` would not.

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to be decidable in general but would be very interested to read a full analysis

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a easy, fast way to do this in python but you can certainly build a function to do this. A [post from the computer science stack exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12876/equivalence-of-regular-expressions) has a detailed explanation on a 4 step process on how to determine whether or not 2 regular expressions are equivalent.